# Show more than 20 songs in Up Next (iTunes)?

Tags: itunes

Currently it is only possible to view the next 20 tracks in Up Next, how does one increase this to 100?

Comment: I found nothing for this in the iTunes plists

Comment: Plists.         ??.....

Comment: Internal preferences see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plist Most of the time they are the files where you can find hidden options.